# R Compare two matrices and if equal then replace with another column

Tags: r, matrix, compare

I have these two matrices. (It is an example; actually the matrix has several items)

matrix1:

```
Samples    Name
 ab_745     jhjf
  cd333     kdwo
 fn_487     asjd
  aa482     ijaf
```

matrix2:

```
     Nr    Samples     Expr.nr
       1     cd858     4838.0
       2     aa482     2384.9
       3    fn_487     3834.8
```

I want to compare both columns and if there is a match, the name in matrix1 is replaced by the name in samples.

Example: fn_487 is replaced by asjd.

I thank you already for your answers.

Comment: Are you sure this is a matrix? It looks like a data frame.

Comment: I have created the table myself for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

These are data frames, no?

```r
library(tidyverse)

matrix1 <- read_table("Samples    Name
 ab_745     jhjf
  cd333     kdwo
 fn_487     asjd
  aa482     ijaf")

matrix2 <- read_table(" Nr    Samples     Expr.nr
       1     cd858     4838.0
       2     aa482     2384.9
       3    fn_487     3834.8")

matrix1 %>% 
  mutate(Samples = case_when(Samples %in% matrix2$Samples ~ Name, 
                             TRUE ~ Samples))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   Samples Name 
#>   <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 ab_745  jhjf 
#> 2 cd333   kdwo 
#> 3 asjd    asjd 
#> 4 ijaf    ijaf
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>